# laravel valet-linux redirect error

Tags: nginx, laravel-valet

I'm running the very useful [`valet-linux`](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux) package for my local dev environment. I recently updated it (using `composer global update`), and now my local Joomla dev sites are not loading properly.

The error in `~/.valet/Log/nginx-error.log` shows multiple occurrences of

```
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *11 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/plg_quickicon_extensionupdate/js/extensionupdatecheck.js?95ac38c67651723d445944ba719bf971 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *38 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js?95ac38c67651723d445944ba719bf971 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *40 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/mod_sampledata/js/sampledata-process.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *42 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/system/js/core.js?95ac38c67651723d445944ba719bf971 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *44 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /administrator/templates/isis/js/template.js?95ac38c67651723d445944ba719bf971 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
2018/08/11 11:00:28 [error] 7825#7825: *62 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/home/admin/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /administrator/templates/isis/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/home/admin/.valet/valet.sock", host: "joomla310.test", referrer: "http://joomla310.test/administrator/index.php"
```

I'm fairly experienced with Apache, but I don't know where to begin debugging the nginx errors. Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installing `valet-linux` resolved the issue. Still not sure what had happened.